# Show admin menu and toolbar in admin post page

Tags: admin-menu, admin-bar

Is there a way to still show the **admin toolbar** and/or the main wordpress **admin menu** in the admin post page?

[image: wordpress edit.php page]

[image: wordpress post.php page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see on that [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2em4l.png) is the *full-screen mode* which is the default mode in the block editor (that applies to Pages, Posts and custom post types), and which is intended to help users to work without distraction.

Secondly, there's also a note in `wp-admin/admin-header.php` which says that `// Default to is-fullscreen-mode to avoid jumps in the UI.` — `is-fullscreen-mode` is a CSS class added to the `<body>` tag indicating a full-screen mode. Therefore, the default mode should not be changed (programmatically).

However, once the page has been loaded, you can turn off the full-screen mode by simply clicking on the three-dot button (which shows "*More tools & options*" when mouse-overed) on the top-right corner of the screen, and from the menu that appears, just click on the "**Fullscreen mode**" option:

[image: Toggle the Fullscreen mode in the block editor]

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Oh that's perfect. Thanks