# Wordpress Admin Panel Left Sidebar No showing on Post create page

Tags: wp-admin, admin, admin-menu

These are two different WordPress sites on post create pages.
The first site has left the admin panel. The second admin panel does not have a left sidebar. How can I add the left sidebar on the second admin panel like the first site?

[image: sample like below]

Comment: The first site may have the Fullscreen mode turned off. See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/376015

Comment: Great, thanks for your suggestion and it work now..